# Cannot get full size dynamic WordPress lightbox image to display

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I am working on a WordPress theme, I'm trying to recreate [this simple image gallery popup](http://codepen.io/robspen/pen/OVjmgW). I have translated everything over from that codepen to WordPress.

The problem I'm having is after making the gallery editable through Advanced Custom Fields plugin (repeater field), I have came stuck at the popup part. The lightbox event fires, but my image is not showing up. It works perfectly when hard-coded, like in the codepen example.

This is my code for the relevant gallery template. I have also set the `add_image_size` in the functions file to two different sizes, one for the thumbnail size to be displayed on the page, and another (`800x800`) to display in the lightbox.

[This](http://www.moppheadstest.craiggarrity.com/gallery/the-other-gallery/) is the test site url where I am working, if that helps.

```
<!-- start gallery lightbox area -->
<?php if(get_field('gallery')) { ?>
<section class="church-gallery">

<ul class="gallery">

    <?php while(has_sub_field('gallery')) { ?>      
        <?php $img = get_sub_field('image'); ?>

            <li>
                <?php if(get_sub_field('image')) { ?>
                <a href="#" class="btn">

                    <img src="<?php echo $img['sizes']['large-gallery']; ?>" alt="<?php if($img['alt']) {
                    echo $img['alt'];
                    } else {
                    echo $img['title']; } ?>" />

                </a>
            </li>

        <?php } ?>

    <?php } ?>

</ul>

<div class="lightbox">

    <div class="lightbox--close">X</div>

    <div class="lightbox--centre">
        <img class="lightbox__content__image" src="<?php echo $img['sizes']['large-gallery']; ?>" alt="<?php if($img['alt']) {
                    echo $img['alt'];
                    } else {
                    echo $img['title']; } ?>" />
    </div>

</div>
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your test page you have an external Javascript file called "script.min.js".

In that script is function that sets the "lightbox__content__image" src to the href of the link clicked (and prevents the normal navigation).

In your example code, the links around your thumbnail images are all `<a href="#" class="btn">`, so the "lightbox__content__image" also gets `src="#"` when the link is clicked.

Change this line:

> `<a href="#" class="btn">`

To:

```
<a href="<?php echo $img['sizes']['large-gallery']; ?>" class="btn">
```

The lightbox function should then work, as it now has an image to show!

There is a secondary problem in that your "thumbnail" images seem to be the same size your full size images, at 800 x 800 px. They're constrained to about 300px only by your css.

You mention using two different image sizes, but that isn't working and you haven't given enough info to work out why.

Anyway, I hope this helps with your main problem!